# How to set a hex color to an ImageView inside a notification?

Tags: android, bitmap, hex, android-notifications

I'm trying to set a color as an image to an ImageView that exists inside a custom notification. I can give it predefined colors by writing this line:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.color.Green);
```

But i want to be able to give it hex color values, and set that as the color. I tried setting the color as the background of the ImageView, but i couldn't get access to it, and the only options i have to access the ImageView are these:

```
remoteViews
    .setImageViewResource()
    .setImageViewBitmap()
    .setImageViewIcon()
    .setImageViewUri()
```

Is there a way to pass in a color by parsing the hex value to any of these?
I think if I was able to create a bitmap and set the bitmap to the image view, it could be done, so i wrote the code bellow to create the bitmap:

```
    int[] colors = {Color.parseColor("#64DD17"), Color.parseColor("#D32F2F")};
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, 10, 10, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

, but i get a *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*. I tried with one element in the `colors` array too, but same error.
What is my error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int[]` is your image; so you create an image `2px` wide, since that's the length of your array. However, you call `createBitmap` and specify that the image is in fact `10px`x`10px`; this is why the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, as Android starts looking for pixels that aren't there.

Using `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, 2, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);` would solve this problem, albeit generate a very tiny image!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: generate png images(or use svg) to put inside the image view, instead of the color you want.

but, if u want to use that approach, you can create a colored bitmap using something like that:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  image.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
```